# Are normally open contactors virtually safe from failing closed?

Tags: power-supply, power, three-phase

Quick question: are normally-open contactors (which I assume are simply high breaking capacity relays) virtually safe from failing closed?

I want to cut off a 400V 3-phase supply using an emergency stop, and I have 2 options:

1. Use a 3-pole emergency stop, and wire the three phases to that button. I don't like the idea of 400V being so close to the user's hands.
2. Wire the contacts of a 3-pole normally-open contactor on the supply line, and wire the emergency stop on the 230V coil.

Three phase is used for heating, not for a giant chainsaw, but the emergency button should still do its job should it be pressed. So is option 2 commonly accepted, and safe enough for an end product? Any norms stating this on which I could rely?

### Edit implementing the answer

I am quite keen on the idea of forcing the user to fix a failure in the redundant system, but I'm trying to limit the number of components as well. Is this a good comromise? I found [this contactor](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/contactors/3949683/), which has 1NC and 1NO auxiliary contacts that we can use.

Since the current in the coils is already very small compared to the switches capability, I made them single pole, if that is acceptable.

[image]

In particular, I'm not sure whether there is a possibility that the auxiliary contacts do not follow the main contacts (meaning the main contacts may fail closed or welded without the auxiliary contacts staying open when normally closed), could you confirm?

Comment: I've seen relays with one or more of their supposedly normally open contacts 'welded' together ... But these may have been under-spec'ed to start with.

Comment: I have seen 30A power relays with fake UL marks weld closed (on). Made quite a mess when they did that (destroyed the product).

Comment: Ditto - seen high current sparks weld contacts permanently together.

Comment: You always have a miniscule chance that the contacts will weld together or there will be a mechanical failure inside the relay/contactor.  But of course even a mechanical switch has this danger.

Comment: I understand trying to reduce the parts count - don't rube-goldberg any more than you have to - but your additional diagram has a some issues: (1) It will reset automatically, meaning that it's easier to absent-mindedly turn it back on.  (2) The Error signals are Safety_OK && Not_Pulled_In, which is not all that useful in my opinion.  My solution, if you replace K11 and K12 with lights and forget the Error rung, requires one auxiliary relay and a button to reset, and a slightly better contactor to handle some cross-coupled redundancy and interlocked reset.

Comment: If you don't care for the cross-coupled redundancy, then you can actually use the contactor that you suggested, but I'd take a serious look at dropping out both contactors if either safety circuit goes down.

Comment: No, on second thought, you need that 4th NO contact to make the explicit reset work.  So you'd need a different contactor anyway and you can get the cross-coupling for free.

Comment: By cross coupled redundancy, do you mean the 2 channels of the e-Stop? How about using a lamp between the 2, like on my updated post? Also, your solution requires one additional contact per contactor, beacause I'm already using the 3 main contacts for the 3 phases. If I don't understand correctly, how would that look like on my 3 phase system?

Comment: So, after much research I managed to find a nice AC3 contactor with 1NO+1NC auxiliary contacts. Does my updated post look ok to you now? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The cross-coupled redundancy was so if one contactor drops out, the other goes with it, even if its safety channel is still on.  Also, the double-redundant safety circuit has nothing to do with current.  There are other ways to make it stick on than welding contacts.  The purpose is to allow one channel to stick on for whatever reason and still be able to shut the system down.  A single channel can't do that.

Comment: Hmm I thought the poles were tied together, such that the only reason for one of them to fail and not the other was that it was welded because of too high a current compared to its capability. I need the other contact on the e-stop but I'll try to have a second channel, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they are not safe from failing closed.  No switch is, mechanical or solid-state.

Therefore, an E-STOP or other safety switch requires at least two overrated contacts that operate independently, so that one getting welded does not prevent the other from operating.

For your option #1, you would wire these in series, but it's not recommended because of the reason you stated and because there's no way to tell that one has failed until they both go.

For your option #2, you would wire these as part of two identical circuits, with all relevant safety switches wired in series, and the two channels wired in parallel and kept separate electrically.  (no crossover wiring)  Then each channel drives the coil of its own contactor, and the contactors are wired in series to control the load.

Also with option #2, you can now create a latching/lockout circuit using the two safety channels and the contactors' auxiliary contacts so that a separate button is required to turn it back on once the safeties are satisfied, and only if both have dropped out.  This forces you to fix a stuck contactor before they both become stuck.

Per a comment, here's one possible version of option #2:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjr1Cr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or, if you have sufficiently deep pockets, you could buy a safety rated PLC and do all of this in software with even more fault-checking and detailed diagnostics.

Please note that I am in a different industry now, and so there may have been some legal changes since I left.  Check the latest electric codes, OSHA regulations, etc., before trusting this (or anything else really) to an operator.

Comment: +1 This is exactly the right way to think about E-stops. Engineering.

Comment: I'd really like to see an example diagram of this.

Comment: @phonetagger: Happy now?

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks. What I had was the e-stop allowing current to go through both the coils or the primary+redundant contactors in series; I'll rewire that in parallel for the reasons you've explained. Interesting fool-proof system, too!

Comment: The big advantage of having parallel channels is to account for one of them finding power by accident and sticking on for that reason.  A single channel in that situation would appear safe as far as the detection logic is concerned, even if it was looped through two contacts of every switch.

Comment: One potentially significant tradeoff that exists in my drawing is what happens if you lose one channel but keep the other: Do you shut off the other contactor as drawn, to make sure that the load stops but allowing a reset because they both dropped out?  Or do you keep the other contactor on, at the risk of a non-redundant failure to stop the load but also locking the circuit into a maintenance-required state?  The expensive PLC option would not have that dilemma, or you might be able to solve it with a few more relays.

Comment: Just make sure that whatever you change does not introduce a single point of failure to stop the load.

Comment: I think the compromise would be to light up a red indicator when one of them sticks to tell the user to change it, which is "Not energised AND contact closed"; I'm trying to find out how to do that...

Comment: What I meant was, if you lose one channel of the safety circuit and keep the other, as in one contact of your E-STOP welded and the other didn't.  As drawn, it'll drop out first the contactor whose circuit still works, and then the other contactor, but then you can't tell that the E-STOP had a problem.  I think I'll go back to the constant-powered safety circuit and find another way to drop out both contactors.  Hang on...

Comment: ...Alright, try this.  How to communicate Error is up to you, but it does require urgent maintenance.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have updated my answer above with what I have in mind, could you tell me what you think of it?

Comment: Updated my post with what I think is the final solution - the user has a way to tell which contactor fails, and also if the failure detection relay fails as well (lit when on, not lit when off). I'm not forcing the user, but that's as few components as we can make it isn't it?

Answer (score 7):

EDIT - the original question referred to relays and not contactors. It might be confusing to see the question now referring to contactors with my answer suggesting the use of a contactor!

People normally use a contactor for this sort of job: -

[image]

Found [here](http://uk.farnell.com/siemens/3rt10263ap00/contactor-ac-3-11kw-400v/dp/4320219). Here's what wiki says about contactors and relays: -

> Unlike general-purpose relays, contactors are designed to be directly
>   connected to high-current load devices. Relays tend to be of lower
>   capacity and are usually designed for both normally closed and
>   normally open applications. Devices switching more than 15 amperes or
>   in circuits rated more than a few kilowatts are usually called
>   contactors. Apart from optional auxiliary low current contacts,
>   contactors are almost exclusively fitted with normally open ("form A")
>   contacts. Unlike relays, contactors are designed with features to
>   control and suppress the arc produced when interrupting heavy motor
>   currents.

[Here](http://ab.rockwellautomation.com/Motor-Control/IEC-Contactors/IEC-Safety-Contactors) is what Rockwell say about safety contactors (you may decide on this as a preferred product): -

> Safety Contactors and 700S Safety Control Relays provide mechanically
>   linked, positively-guided contacts up to 97 A which are required in
>   feedback circuits for modern safety applications. 100S-D Safety
>   Contactors provide safe isolation of hazardous motion loads, using
>   mirror contact performance. Mirror contacts provide reliable
>   indication about the open or closed status of the main power poles.

And finally, the EU machinery directive implies that hazards be assessed and appropriate safety measures taken. The impact of this is that equipment/installations can be categorized with a letter/number and appropriate equipment purchased to maintain that level of safety. I would recommend that you look into this. [Here](http://www.safety-relay.com/monitoring_relay.html) is a website related to safety relays that discusses the relevant safety categories. Incidentally you may need to use a category 3 contactor.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I was referring to high current rating relays, updated my question. My question still stands for contactors: are they virtually safe from failing closed?

Answer (score 4):

Whatever the manufacturer may or may not say, I would strongly urge you to limit the consequences of such a failure by adding redundant safety features such as a thermal cutoff or mechanical stop so that injuries and intolerable property damage are prevented. Even if the relay is 100.000% reliable from that kind of failure, the driving circuitry could fail or something could jam the contactor test button or whatever.

Some products have three safety devices- one electrical, one hydraulic and one purely mechanical, because a failure could result in severe injury to an operator.

Comment: Important comment, but I don't see how that answers the question...

Comment: When I was working in industrial automation, we always had two overrated contactors in series to provide a safety stop function.  Neither one is likely to weld, but if one does anyway, the other is probably still good.  Their coils were controlled by separate, mechanically parallel systems, which included a bit of logic around the contactors' auxiliary contacts so that it cannot be reset unless they both dropped out.  (That is, if one welded or one channel of a detector failed, the system will refuse to re-energize until that's fixed.)

Comment: Good point, this is simply as a primary means of emergency stop.

Comment: Note that 99.9996% rounds to 100.000%. :)

Comment: Not when you're dealing with safety.  A known point of failure can become a legal liability in a hurry, even if it's only 0.0004% likely to happen.  Hence the redundancy of every shutdown function, not just multiple functions.

Comment: I think we meant the same thing. If you measure 100.000% reliability but the real value is 99.9996%, you still don't have perfect protection. Redundancy is important.