# How can I add redundancy to the flyback diode protection across an inductive load?

Tags: zener, solenoid, flyback, redundancy

Dear StackExchange users,

I want to add redundancy to a flyback diode system that is protecting an N channel MOSFET from flyback of an inductive load but I don't know how to accomplish this!

I am using a Zener Diode + normal diode. I think when the Zener is going bad, then it will conduct the current without any resistance, So adding a parallel diodes is not going to work.

What shall I do?

Thank  you

[image]

Comment: You have redundancy already. Normally the relay clamps at Vz+0.7. If the zener fails short circuit it still clamps but at 0.7v. If the fail mode of the zener is open circuit then put two zeners in parallel. If D2 fails short circuit put two in series. If D2 fails open circuit have independent zener/diode circuits.

Comment: What's the point of the redundancy? The most likely parts to fail are the transistor and the relay.

Comment: @Andyaka: Thank you very much. How can I find out if the failures of diodes are open or short? Should I deliberately try to fail them to find out? Or is there a better way to find out?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: Yes. That's true. My testing platform is extremely expensive and any failure in MOSFET can cause huge damage.

Comment: In that case I suggest two independent drivers and relays with the contacts in series. And a detection circuit to tell you when one has failed 'on' (assuming that's the state to be avoided).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany could you tell me more about it? I don't much about electronics. Especially about the detection circuit!! I'd be thankful if you could give a through explanation. I was able to test the platform successfully with your help (from my other questions). Thanks.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77712/can-a-diode-fail-to-open-position

Comment: @Andyaka so I think I should count for both short and open failures as it is not predictable which mode of failuer will happen? Is it true?

Comment: Here is another thread worth reading:
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/157032/are-normally-open-contactors-virtually-safe-from-failing-closed

Comment: I think you should consider using beefier components as a means to improve reliability. You should also review the stresses on all components that are relevant to the functioning of the whole circuit especially power supply diodes as an example. On the limited circuit you provided this is the only advice anyone could give. I think it's called MIL-HDBK-417F. This is an old document by todays standards but I still use it for determining reliability. It's online too

Comment: Thank you, Vcc is 12V, I have solenoid valves (0.015H, 20ohm,12V,7Watt), 5KP70A Zener (70V,8watt) and 1N5408 diode. The only part that I am worrying about is 5KP70A. I don't know if it can endure 0.6A current or not !!!

Comment: MIL-HDBK-217F: http://www.sre.org/pubs/Mil-Hdbk-217F.pdf. Why are you using a 70V zener diode for flyback protection?

Comment: Because turn off speed of the valves are crucial for me. Higher zener Voltage = Higher turn off speed. I am worried about its amperage rating. Oh by the way, I am using an IRFP260N MOSFET

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=rnKmmCqLTW4C&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=failure+modes+of+zener+diodes&source=bl&ots=xff9f4bkYS&sig=OfHASqTStIv5CkKGW36npEMBEIE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bP6cVd_lGoO_ygPM9Iu4Cg&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=failure%20modes%20of%20zener%20diodes&f=false

Comment: 5KP70A isn't a zener -- it's a TVS. These are not very precise, and while it seems the specs can handle the instantaneous power, you need to determine if it can handle the energy, and the average power (how frequently do you activate the solenoid ?)